# Sharepoint 2013: Wiki page -how do I embed another page? the other wiki pages do not show in webparts

Tags: web-part

I am trying to create a wiki and to add a menu at the right side of my layount. That is a column where I would like to embed a content page that will be common to all my wiki pages. 
How do I do that? 
Iframe is not allowed
I tried to add a webpart but there is way I can see the wiki pages I have created in the folder /app list that opens up when you click on add webparts

Comment: Can you not use the Page Viewer Web Part?

Comment: I am trying but it has no effect, after I add the link to the other wiki page and I do apply and save the webpart shows up as it would be empty and waits to be configured (i.e. to add a link there, the initial config dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Script Editor Web-Part and insert Iframe code pointing to another page:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Wiki/SitePages/Page2.aspx" scrolling="no" style="margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -200px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I do not have that option in WebParts You are probably referring to this https://i.imgur.com/kd3gSHd.png